# Can't Get indexPath of Clicked Cell ( where Cell is CustomTableViewCell`)

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a TableView and separate TableViewCell (with .xib). I am trying to select the clicked cell. If I understood right, I think it's fine for my case if I get the `indexPath.row` to be able to get/read data from object.

What I tried...

```
@IBOutlet var tableView1: UITableView!

...

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // First tried this, but no luck. Nothing gets printed in console.
        print(indexPath.row)

    // Also, nothing in console
       print(results?[indexPath.row])

   // Then tried this, but no luck either.. nothing in console
       let indexPath = tableView1.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let currentCell = tableView1.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
        print(currentCell)
}
```

This is what I use in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`..

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyCustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil),
        forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomTableViewCell")

    let cell : DiscoverTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCustomTableViewCell") as! DiscoverTableViewCell

    cell.photo = self.results?[indexPath.row]

    return cell
```

Both of the trials are not returning anything in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does "no luck" even mean? What actually happens? A minimal SO question needs at least to describe the desired phenomenon and the actual phenomenon.

Comment: Have you added `tableView1.delegate = self` and mapped your TableView's delegate to your view controller?

Comment: @matt Nothing happens, nothing gets printed. @R P, I just tried adding `tableView1.delegate = self` in viewDidLoad(). Also, I don't know if that might be the reason, but I also have `tableView1.allowsSelection = false` to be able to turn off grey cell selection indicator.

Comment: @matt I edited the question. Is it more descriptive now?

Comment: To disable the highlighting for selection in UITableView, you should set the cell's selectionStyle to .None. Setting the UITableView's allowSelection property to false does, in fact, prevent selection.

Comment: `tableView1.allowsSelection = false` blocks cell selection, so, your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` never gets called. You will have to set `tableView1.allowsSelection = true` and set your cell's `selectionStyle` property to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None` to achieve your result

Comment: Ah! So `allowsSelection` is the thing blocking selection. But, I got a bit confused with you guys (@geraldWilliam @RP) answers. Should I use `tableView1.allowsSelection = false` or just delete it? Can one of you add an answer below?

Comment: You can remove that line

Comment: I made it work. and just `print(results?[indexPath.row])` in didSelectRowAtIndexPath works like charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tableView1.allowsSelection = false` in your code blocks cell selection, so, your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` never gets called.

You will have to set `tableView1.allowsSelection = true` and in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function set your cell's `selectionStyle` property to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None` to achieve your result.